# Are all fetched objects from remote are being pushed forward (replicated) to other repos?

Tags: git

I've set-up multiple git remotes as part of one Git repository and I need to cherry-pick one specific commit from the remote, but I don't want to push anything else to other repos (for the privacy purposes).

So when I fetch all the objects from remote A (from the same branch), cherry pick one commit (1 commit from A into B & C) and push it back to other remotes (B & C), does all objects (fetched from A) are pushed to (B & C, with possibility to browse), or only these which are associated (cherry-picked) with the current branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only your picked commit will be pushed on `git cherry-pick` as a commit a complete object. The pick is merging the changes into history tree not as e.g. `git merge` merging the complete tree.

You could also give it a try setting up a remote D ;)